# CMake Could NOT find wxWidgets

Tags: windows, cmake, saga

I am trying to compile SAGA-GIS API on Windows using the following instructions https://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/wiki/Compiling%20SAGA%20on%20Windows/

I have followed the compilation step-by-step and gotten to the point of compiling SAGA. As I'm an inexperienced user of CMake, I user CMake-GUI and it's instructions for compiling. However, I keep running into this error

```
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19044.
The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30143.0
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30143.0
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
folder: saga
Found Git: C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe (found version "2.31.1.windows.1") 
GIT_BRANCH:         master
VERSON_STRING:      8.4.0
VERSON_FULL_STRING: 8.4.0-256+17a31eb88
compile with OpenMP optimizations
folder: src
folder: accessories
folder: saga_core
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_LIBRARIES
  wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake:977 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  src/saga_core/CMakeLists.txt:16 (find_package)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/saga-gis-code/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

See screenshot:
[image]

Comment: So, have you installed wxWidgets as the guide notes? Have you set `WXWIN` environment variable pointed to that installation? What exact value have you assigned to that variable?

Comment: @Tsyvarev see the screenshot attached

Comment: On the screenshot I see the variable `wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR` to be set, which should denote root of wxWidgets installation. But since variable `wxWidgets_LIB_DIR` is NOTFOUND, it seems that it is NOT an actual installation of the wxWidgets. What is content of `lib/` subdirectory of that directory?

Comment: A shell script and 6 ```OPT``` scripts starting with VMS

Comment: [That files](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/tree/master/lib)? This is **source code** of vxWidgets, you need to build and install it for use vxWidgets in other projects.

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes they're all the files I'm seeing. I will try building it now

Comment: @Tsyvarev even with it built and installed I'm getting this error. The ```/lib``` folder now has ```vc_dll``` and ```vc_lib``` folders in it too